# I have a class that looks like this following:

Tags: c++, oop

```
class ContUser
{
    char *display_Name;
    char *email;
    char password[10];
    const int id_user;
    char user_type;
    int badges_nr;
    char **badges;

     ContUser(char *dn, char *e, char p[10],int id,char tip) : id_utilizator(id) {
        display_Name = new char[strlen(dn) + 1];
        strcpy(display_Name, dn);

        email = new char[strlen(e) + 1];
        strcpy(email, e);
    }
};
```

I  have an error:

> display_Name 0xcccccccc error reading character of string;

at both of objects, `displayname` and `email`, and I can't realize why. [This is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flSZ4.png) (Unable to read memory).

This is the part where i created an instance of ContUser

```
void main()
{
    ContUtilizator c2("Mariam31", "mariam@yahoo.com", "Passwordd", 12, 'V');
    c2.display();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use simply `std::string` instead of raw character `char*` pointers?

Comment: ***I have an error at both of objects*** What error? Be specific. If it is a compiler error and this is Visual Studio copy the text of error message from the Output tab and paste it in your question.

Comment: pls, show us part of the code where you create an instance of ContUser

Comment: I added the error and the part where i create an instance of ContUser. I used the pointer char* because i must use it,as a request from my teacher.

Comment: _"display_Name 0xcccccccc error reading character of string;"_ that doesn't look like a compiler message. Could you tell us where you're getting it and the _exact_ text? In brief - give a [mcve].

Comment: I solved the problem,thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite the class using the standard template library. This could be done for the snippet you provided as follows:

```
class ContUser
{
    std::string display_Name;
    std::string email;
    std::string password;
    const int id_user;
    char user_type;
    int badges_nr;
    std::vector< std::string> > badges;

    ContUser(char *dn, char *e, char p[10], int id, char tip) : id_utilizator(id)
    {
        display_Name = std::string(dn);
        email = std::string(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: You should change the constructor of the class as well.